# Precision issues with dlmwrite / dlmread

Tags: matlab, double, precision, writefile

I recently discovered, quite harshly, that Matlab's `dlmread` and `dlmwrite` don't store numerical values at `double` accuracy. It effects my code, and I need to store big arrays with more precision.

A (not) working example :

```
pi1 = pi;
dlmwrite('pi',pi1);
pi2 = dlmread('pi');
pi1-pi2

ans =

-7.3464e-06
```

While I'd expect machine-error answer, of 10^-14 accuracy.

I'd much rather keep using a simple function as `dlmwrite`, but I will consider other solutions.

Thanks

Comment: RTFM: [The default precision is 5 significant digits and it supports C-style format strings](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html#input_argument_namevalue_precision). As an alternative, `dlmwrite` is a wrapper for the lower-level [`fwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html) function.

Answer (score 3):

You can get more precise results by using the `precision` property of the function. Check this example:

```
format long
S = pi * rand

S =

   2.869454879612631

dlmwrite('test1.txt',S,'precision','%10.3f');
dlmwrite('test2.txt',S,'precision','%10.5f');
dlmwrite('test3.txt',S,'precision','%10.9f');
dlmwrite('test3.txt',S,'precision','%2.14f');
```

The result is as follows:

- test1.txt with 3 decimals  `2.869`
- test2.txt with 5 decimals  `2.86945`
- test3.txt with 9 decimals  `2.869454880`
- test4.txt with 14 decimals `2.86945487961263`